# Property [kodeSparepart] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I want to get all of the data from sparepart database using all() function, then use foreach in view to access the data, but I keep get that error. It works fine when I use the same method for other view blade.

Controller

```
  public function LaporanSisaStok(Request $request) {

    if($request->kode == "")
    {
        $spareparts = Sparepart::all();
        return view('laporan/sisaStok')->with(['spareparts' => $spareparts]);
    }
    else {
        $query = DB::table("historisparepart")->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggal) AS Bulan, SUM(jumlah) as Sisa'))
        ->where('kodeSparepart', $request->kode)
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggal)'))
        ->get();
        return view('printPreview/sisaStok', ['data'=>$query]);
    }
}
```

View

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('laporan.sisaStok') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="form-group-row">
    <label for="sparepart" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sparepart</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="kode" name="kode">
        <option value="">-Pilih Sparepart-</option>
        foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)
        {
            <option value="{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}"> {{$sparepart->namaSparepart}} </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="oi oi-task"></i> Cari </button>
```

[image: dd result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't looping through anything.  You need to give the `foreach()` method a variable from your spareparts *collection*.  I think it might help you avoid confusion, to name the collection variables plural:

In your **controller**:

```
$spareparts = Sparepart::all();
return view('laporan/sisaStok', compact('spareparts'));
```

Then, most importantly, you need to tell foreach what it should produce.  In your **view**, change:

```
foreach($sparepart)
```

to

```
@foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)
```

Don't forget you are in blade, so use the `@` before the foreach.  Then, assuming you actually have a property on the spareparts model called `kodeSparepart`, this should work fine.

Comment: still the same problem. I tried to use first() method and it works, but it only get the first data.

Comment: This should work.  If you dd() `$spareparts` in the view what does it show?  IE if you open up one of the dumped $sparepart from the dd, does it have kodeSparepart?

Comment: OK, that's good news, it means the collection has the property and it is correctly getting to the view.  Sorry for silly question, but are you sure you have changed the foreach in the view to `foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)` like in the answer above?  If the collection variable is `$spareparts`, and it has the result of the all() from the controller, the `<option value="{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}">` from inside the view foreach loop really must work...

Comment: Yeah, and if I try to use other variable for the foreach, IE ` foreach($sparepart as $s)` It return with `undefined variable s.`.

Comment: Um... did you try `foreach($sparepart as $s)` or was that a typo in your comment and you actually tried `foreach($spareparts as $s)`?  I think this is all coming back to a simple typo perhaps.  If you very carefully change exactly per my answer, this really should work.  Sorry, just trying to help:)

Comment: Yeah I try with your advice and it returned with `Undefined variable: sparepart` . I update my post with full code of my controller and view in the post, maybe I make a mistake in the rest of the code

Comment: Wracking my brain, and I can't see anything wrong.  Suggest you bug test by removing everything on the view page, and just putting the foreach loop and just `{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}` inside it to see if that works.  If so, possibly something in the form is messing up.

Comment: OH!!!  Maybe it was just a typo.  I've edited my answer, but please check that you have the `@` sign in the blade file before the foreach and remove the brackets {} to replace with @endforeach.  LOL, maybe a typo after all?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use the plural of your dtb name to loop over the values so your 'sparepart' variable should change to 'spareparts'

```
$sparepart = Sparepart::all();
return view('laporan/sisaStok')->with(['spareparts' => $sparepart]);
```

In your view change your loop to the new variable and loop using your current variable, so your view shoul look like this:

View

```
<div class="form-group-row">
    <label for="sparepart" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sparepart</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="kode" name="kode">
        <option value="">-Pilih Sparepart-</option>
        @foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)
        {
            <option value="{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}"> {{$sparepart->namaSparepart}} </option>
        }
        @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a looping syntax in the laravel view

```
  foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)
    {
        <option value="{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}"> {{$sparepart->namaSparepart}} </option>
    }
```

It should be like this

```
@foreach($spareparts as $sparepart)
<option value="{{$sparepart->kodeSparepart}}"> {{$sparepart->namaSparepart}} </option>
 @endforeach
```

And another problem is  you are passing the data in wrong way. It should be like this

```
  return view('printPreview/sisaStok', ['spareparts'=>$query]);
```

Comment: yeah! Thx for your advice!